# matlab ode45 how to change a parameter inside the function continiously

Tags: matlab, ode

i am trying to solve a differential equation using ode45, I have a function in which one of the parameters has to vary by specific step, here is my function:

```
function f=RSJ(y,t,M1,P,M2,E,current)

f=(current/P)-(M1/P)*sin(y)+(M2/P)*sin(y+E);
```

`P`, `M1`, `M2` & `E` are numerical constants, `current` is the parameter which I should resolve this differential equation for several cases, for example `current=0:1:10`
how can I do such a thing?

Comment: I would rather suggest you to ask in the math section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a closure (a.k.a. anonymous or lambda function):

```
% declare t, y, tspan and y0
% [...]
current = 6e-7 : 1e-8 : 8.5e-7;
for k=1:length(current)
    f = @(y, t, M1, P, M2, E) (current(k)/P)-(M1/P)*sin(y)+(M2/P)*sin(y+E);
    [t{k}, y{k}] = ode45(f, tspan, y0);
end
```

Comment: What do you mean? ∂y/∂t = y' = f(t,y), the problem you are solving is finding y(t).

Comment: I found out the following code will give me dy/dt:        ydot=y(:,2) , but when I tried this I got dy/dt for 1 current, how can I get dy/dt for different currents?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking but each iteration returns y(t) for a given current, yes. Here I saved them in a cell array so as not to erase the result from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution. Define `current` as a global variable (you need to do this in both the base workspace and in the function) and use a `for` loop, e.g.

```
current_vector=1e-7*(6:0.1:8.5);
global current
for k=1:length(current_vector)
    current = current_vector(k);
    [t{k},y{k}]=ode45(f,<tspan>,<y0>)
end
```

Replace `<tspan>` and `<y0>` by the appropriate values/variables. I assume the other constants are defined in the body of the function, in which case your function should look something like this:

```
function f=RSJ(t,y)
    global current
    M1 = ... % etc...
    f=(current/P)-(M1/P)*sin(y)+(M2/P)*sin(y+E);
end
```

BTW, I don't see any explicit dependence on time `t` in your function...

Comment: your solution worked, but what if I want to change current like this: current=6.00*10^(-7):0.1*10^(-7):8.5*10^(-7), & also y is a function of time.

Comment: I have edited my answer to accommodate the new values for `current`.

Comment: No. No. There is no need to use global variables. This is not what they're for. The value of `current` should be passed in to `ode45` as a parameter by declaring it in the integration function `f`. @user2822314, see the solution from @Simon.

Comment: @horchler I agree. I did say it was "quick and dirty".